# PHP - magic quotes gpc and stripslashes question

Tags: php, stripslashes, magic-quotes-gpc

Okay my hosting company has `magic_quotes_gpc` turned `ON` and I coded my PHP script using `stripslashes()` in preparation of this. But now the hosting company says its going to turn `magic_quotes_gpc` OFF and I was wondering what will happen now to my data now when `stripslashes()` is present should I go through all my millions of lines of code and get rid of `stripslashes()`? or leave the `stripslashes()` function alone? will leaving the `stripslashes()` ruin my data?

Comment: Millions of lines of code?  Really?

Comment: @ircmaxell well a million and one lines of code!

Comment: @ircmaxwell, they're developing the next os in php

Answer (score 10):

Your code should use [`get_magic_quotes_gpc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php) to see if magic quotes are enabled, and only strip slashes if they are. You should run a block of code similar to the following in exactly one place, shared by all your scripts; if you're using `stripslashes` in multiple places you're doing it wrong.

```
// recursively strip slashes from an array
function stripslashes_r($array) {
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $array[$key] = is_array($value) ?
      stripslashes_r($value) :
      stripslashes($value);
  }
  return $array;
}

if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
  $_GET     = stripslashes_r($_GET);
  $_POST    = stripslashes_r($_POST);
  $_COOKIE  = stripslashes_r($_COOKIE)
  $_REQUEST = stripslashes_r($_REQUEST);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would start going through and removing `stripslashes()`.  You can do this ahead of time by testing for `magic_quotes_gpc` and only calling `stripslahes()` if it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

meagar has the correct answer.

But to traverse the situation, you need something like Notepad++ with a Search within files function. Copy a snippet of meagar's code and search for stripslashes()