# Escaping raw HTML data inserted into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" border="1">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td height="30" bgcolor="#006699" align="center" class="heading" colspan="6" style="color:#fff; font-size:22px;">hello this is test</td>
    </tr>
```

```
<table width="\\100%\\" cellspacing=\\"1\\" cellpadding=\\"0\\" border=\\"1\\">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td height=\\"30\\" bgcolor=\\"#006699\\" align=\\"center\\" style=\\"color:#fff; font-size:22px;\\" colspan=\\"3\\" class=\\"heading\\">hello this is test </td>
    </tr></tbody></table>
```

Is it possible that i can just remove the backslashes, from this?

Comment: and how are these backslashes coming?

Comment: @user2936213 That's what he's asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server has [Magic Quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) enabled. You can contact your host and ask them to disable it, or before you send the data to your query you can use `stripslashes()` on it. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315406/php-magic-quotes-gpc-and-stripslashes-question#answer-4315456) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

In your host probably has magic_quotes_runtime turned on. 
You can turn it off with **set_magic_quotes_runtime(0)**.

Please turn off magic_quotes_runtime, and then change your code to use bind variables, rather than using the string escaping If you are using mysql_real_escape_string .

To make sure there are no slashes in that value, you can apply

```
echo "Magic quotes is " . (get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? "ON" : "OFF");
```

Or you can perform a .htaccess edit to turn off magic_quotes, add the following line in your .htaccess file

```
php_flag magic_quotes off
```